# What exactly makes SwiftUI list refresh?

Tags: swiftui-list

I am having a problem with understanding the sequence of how the code behaves.
In my AppDelegate.swift I have

```
 var parts: [Part] = []
```

In my ContentsView.swift I have

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let appDelegate = NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    
    @State private var searchFor = ""

TextField("start typing part name here...", text: $searchFor)
    .frame(maxWidth: 185, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .onReceive(searchFor.publisher, perform: { _ in
        appDelegate.parts = []
        appDelegate.parts.append(contentsOf: appDelegate.db.read(fragment: searchFor))
    })
List(appDelegate.parts) {part in
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/nil/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, content: {
        Text(part.name)
        Text(part.group)
        Text(part.parameters)
        Text(String(part.price))
        Divider()
    })
```

So, when I start typing a phrase inside TextField, immediately when I type in a letter, I can see that parts array is updated (with results from db.read). However, the list refreshes only with the next letter is typed into TextField. Why is it so?

Comment: You should watch demystifying SwiftUI from wwdc21

Comment: i've just watched it, but this doesn't make it clear. I tried moving the array to ContentView, declaring it as @State var partsArray : [Part] = []
but that made things even worse - the app was continuosly performing the same query for no obvious reason.  
 could you please explain, what's wrong with my code? this works fine, but fro the list to update I have to type in (or remove) yet another character.